# How to iterate through a variadic tuple in a variadic template function?

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, variadic-functions, stdtuple

I was writing a CSV parser and I thought it would be a great idea to put in practice some advanced  C++. In particular, there's a useful function to split a line of a CSV file given a delimiter. Although it's a straightfoward function to write, now I want that function to return a tuple with a varying number of arguments and types. For example :

```
int main() {
    auto [a, b, c] = extract<int, std::string, float>("42;hello;3.1415", ';');
    std::cout << a << ' ' << b << ' ' << c << std::endl;
}
```

Should print out :

`42 hello 3.1415`

So I thought of a variadic template function :

```
template <typename... T>
std::tuple<T...> extract(const std::string&& str, const char&& delimiter) {
    std::tuple<T...> splited_line;

    /* ... */

    return splited_line;
}
```

But I can't modify the tuple inside that function with a variable parameter, like so :

```
std::get<i>(splited_line) // doesn't work
```

That wasn't a big surprise, I'm quite new to this language. I'm now wondering how to achieve this small function in a elegant way.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The existing parameters to `extract` should be normal references. `&&` accomplishes absolutely nothing, whatsoever, here. With that out of the way: step 1: use `std::apply` to pass each value in a tuple ***by reference*** to a `template<typename ...Args> void helper(const std::string& str, const char& delimiter, Args & ...args)`. Step 2: implement `helper()` using elementary variadic parameter pack techniques to do your extraction. Although normally, on stackoverflow.com, we don't write entire programs, from scratch, for others, someone who needs karma will probably do it...

Comment: Thanks, I'll try out! I wasn't asking for a full program but more of guidelines like yours ;)

Answer (score 3):

You might do something like (I let you implement "parsing" part):

```
// Parsing parts
std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string& s, char delimiter);

template <typename T>
T ConvertTo(const std::string& s);


// Variadic part
template <typename... Ts, std::size_t ... Is>
std::tuple<Ts...> extract_impl(std::index_sequence<Is...>,
                               const std::vector<std::string>& v)
{
    return { ConvertTo<Ts>(v[Is])... };
}

template <typename... Ts>
std::tuple<Ts...> extract(const std::string& s, char delimiter) {
    const auto strings = split(s, delimiter);

    if (strings.size() != sizeof...(Ts)) {
        // Error handling
        // ...
    }
    return extract_impl<Ts...>(std::index_sequence_for<Ts...>(), strings);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
template<class F>
auto foreach_argument( F&& f ) {
  return [f = std::forward<F>(f)](auto&&...elems) {
    ( (void)f(elems), ... );
  };
}

template <class... Ts>
std::tuple<Ts...> extract(const std::string& str, const char delimiter) {
  std::tuple<Ts...> splited_line;

  std::size_t i = 0;
  std::size_t index = 0;
  auto operation = [&](auto&& elem){
    if (index == std::string::npos)
      return;
    auto next = str.find( delimiter, index );
    std::string element = str.substr( index, next );
    index = next;
    // parse the string "element" into the argument "elem"
    ++i;
  };
  std::apply(foreach_argument(operation), splitted_line);

  return splited_line;
}
```

this results in default-constructed `Ts` first, and if the element isn't found it remains default-constructed.

The return value

```
std::optional<std::tuple<Ts...>>
```

or throw-if-not-matching options would have a

```
std::tuple<std::optional<Ts>...>
```

within the function, and the lambda in `apply` would `.emplace` the element when it was found.  Then ensure that all elements are valid before returning, else throw or return the empty optional.

Ie, to turn a `std::tuple<std::optional<Ts>...>>` into a `std::tuple<Ts...>` something like:

```
return std::apply( [](auto&&elems){ return std::make_tuple( *elems... ); }, splitted_line );
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, thanks to the help of the community, I got my problem solved. Maybe it'll help someone understands variadic template functions, so I'm going to share a working code (based on Adam Nevraumont's code) :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>
#include <string_view>
#include <sstream>

template <typename... Ts>
std::tuple<Ts...> extract(std::string_view str, char delimiter = ';') {
    size_t idx = 0;
    auto pop = [&](auto&& elem) {
        auto next = str.find(delimiter, idx);
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << str.substr(idx, next - idx);
        ss >> elem;
        idx = next + 1;
    };

    std::tuple<Ts...> splited;
    std::apply([&](auto&&...elems) { (pop(elems), ...); }, splited);
    return splited;
}

int main() {
    std::string dataline = "-42;hello;3.1415;c";
    auto [i, s, f, c] = extract<int, std::string, float, char>(dataline);
    std::cout << i << " " << s  << " " << f << " " << c << std::endl;
}
```

As you can see, I convert string into the type I want with stringstream... maybe if you have more control on the type you're handling in the tuple, you have to implement an another template variadic function and then specialize it (based on Jarod42's code) :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>
#include <string_view>

template <typename T> T convert_to(const std::string_view& s) { return T(); } // default constructor
template <> std::string convert_to(const std::string_view& s) { return std::string(s); }
template <>       float convert_to(const std::string_view& s) { return std::stof(std::string(s)); }
template <>         int convert_to(const std::string_view& s) { return std::stoi(std::string(s)); }

template <typename... Ts, size_t... Is>
std::tuple<Ts...> extract_impl(std::index_sequence<Is...>,
                               std::string_view splited[sizeof...(Ts)]) {
    return { convert_to<Ts>(splited[Is])... };
}

template <typename... Ts>
std::tuple<Ts...> extract(std::string_view str, char delimiter = ';') {
    std::string_view splited[sizeof...(Ts)];
    for (size_t i = 0, idx = 0; i < sizeof...(Ts); ++i) {
        auto next = str.find(delimiter, idx);
        splited[i] = str.substr(idx, next - idx);
        idx = next + 1;
    }
    return extract_impl<Ts...>(std::index_sequence_for<Ts...>(), splited);
}

int main() {
    auto [a, b, c] = extract<int, std::string, float>("-42;hello;3.1415");
    std::cout << a << ' ' << b << ' ' << c;
}
```